# Large memory support for bottom language

Tags: discussion

Assuming an algorithm requires an array of 10<sup>80</sup> bytes of RAM(maybe not realistic, but theoretically the algorithm work). For languages like Python, `[0]*(10**80)` just theoretically work (ignoring optimizing here), but for C, currently there's only 64-bit machine, and avaliable RAM far not enough.

What is the default when such happens? (inf-bit machine or what)

Comment: Why would the algorithm require that much memory? Is it parametrized? (for example is it `10ⁿ` where `n` is the input)

Comment: @user202729 maybe. Lots of code-golf use more time and space for shorter code, so large cost usually happen

Comment: Partial asnwer: Allowing python to do something like `[0]*(10**80)` isn't really that different than allowing lenguage/unary to compete, so I don't think there's any problem with that as long as it can be proven to be correct. However, since C can only address a finite amount of space, no hypothetical computer could ever run a C program that addresses more, so that shouldn't be valid.

Comment: Python (specifically CPython) is subject to the same memory constraints as C, and the same solution works for both: virtual memory and paging.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem It can address more memory, using an arch where `sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BIT` is larger. Still finite, however.